# How to update elegantly the Failure exception of a Try?

Tags: scala, try-catch

I would like to update the Failure exception of a Try to provide a more understandable failure.

I successfully do this by using the following implementation:

```
case class NoDataAvailableException() extends Exception

[...]

    Try(...) match {
      case Success(f) => Success(f)
      case Failure(_) => Failure(NoDataAvailableException())
    }
```

But I think this implementation is not really elegant, so my question is:

***Is there a way to do this more elegantly ?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `recoverWith` with accepts a `PartialFunction[Throwable, Try[U]]`. This would allow you to map specific exceptions to successes or failures, as you wish.

```
case class MyException() extends Exception

Try(1 / 0) recoverWith {
    case _: ArithmeticException => Failure(new MyException())
    // other exceptions ...
}
```

You could also use an implicit class to add method of your own to `Try` that lets you specifically map exceptions.

```
implicit class TryExtension[A](t: Try[A]) {
    def mapFailure(pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, Throwable]): Try[A] =
        t.recoverWith(pf.andThen(Failure.apply))
}

scala> Try(1 / 0).mapFailure { case _ => new MyException }
res3: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(MyException)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `Try.recoverWith`

```
Try(...) recoverWith {
    case _ => Failure(NoDataAvailableException())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using try.recover or try.recoverWith?